# custom mp3 player/phone for blind person controlled by mini numpad keyboard

Tags: audio-playback, gsm

My 86 y.o. father can barely see and can not use ordinary keyboard and touch-screen devices. Also it's hard for him to use modern youth-oriented miniature devices with small keys on them. Obviously, he cannot use any standard application or run OS.

So I want to build custom device for him, where I will control everything.
I can attach small screen and display large and contrast text on it. 
I can attach mini keyboard with numpad (like 18-number keys only keyboard), and do all kind of control using this keyboard.

So far I managed to connect all of those hardware parts and everything works.

Task #1 for me is creation of MP3 player, which will read audio-books and will be controlled from this numpad keyboard, and displaying some large text on screen - like played book name. It should be big and distinctive, so I cannot use console for it (probably).

But I have less experience with Linux UI programming (while 15-y.o. experience with C#/Delphi/C++ developing on Windows).

Can someone recommend what approach I should use?
Should I start PIXEL and run some app which will exclusively take all the screen? Or shouldn't I start it at all?
What will be the easiest way to go - Some Python library? Qt?

My next task is creation of custom cell phone application, which will play names from the address book and will be, again, controlled by numpad keyboard.

(Note: So far I don't want to go with Windows 10 IoT Core, since very much afraid it can do simple things like playing mp3 files or support GSM phone calls)

Comment: Awesome project! Just ideas: you can control the VLC media player by cli (indirect way: shell script or PHP and more). You could set up a web server to provide the interactive gui with big touch buttons. How about voice control like Alexa?

Comment: If you have 15 years of programming experience, it should not be hard to research this as long as you avoid using "raspberry pi" in your search terms; the brand of hardware in this context is no more relevant than it would be if you wanted to do this on a Windows laptop and searched "Dell laptop GUI" instead of "Windows GUI". The operating system in this case is colloquially "linux".  The specific [DE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) (PIXEL) is not very relevant either; the DE is not part of the software stack. GUI apps on linux predominantly use the Qt or GTK+ libraries.

Comment: ...But asking about "the best way" here is simply too broad and opinion oriented for our format.  If you have specific questions, they are probably more appropriate to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).